# retrofit android send failed pipe broken

Tags: android, retrofit, multipart

I use retrofit in my android project to create a multipart request which upload an audio file and some parameters.This is my interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/app/subassignment/upload.json")

void uploadRecord(@Part("file")TypedFile recordFile,@Part("size") long size,Callback<Map<String,Object>> callback);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
service.uploadRecord(file,size,new Callback<Map<String, Object>>() 
{

      @Override
            public void success(Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap, Response response) {
                Message msg=new Message();
                msg.obj=stringObjectMap;
                msg.what=MESSAGE_UPLOADING_STOP;
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                handler.sendMessage(createErrorMsg(error.getMessage()));
                Log.e(RECORDER_TAG,"error--"+error.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

sometimes fail and give me message:sendto failed: EPIPE (Broken pipe).
but sometimes it success.
someone can help me?

Comment: Can you post the whole log as well ?

Comment: It might be because your internet connection sometimes breaks.

Comment: @YeLinAung I just have tested few times ,it didn't fail;once fail again i will post the log.thanks all the same.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem now i doubt too